# How does variable memory allocation work?

Tags: java, android, variables, memory, out-of-memory

When I create new object for String builder and use that variable then how memory allocation work  and what is result of my code snippet my sample code is

1)

```
String nextPoint=new StringBuilder().append("My").append("next").append("point").toString();

System.out.println(nextPoint);
```

2)

```
StringBuilder downPoint=new StringBuilder().append("My").append("next").append("point");

System.out.println(downPoint.toString());
```

Which variables/instance can consume memory?? which solution is better when i'm using "nextPoint" varaible or "downPoint" variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which variables/instance can consume memory?

Every class occupies memory.  How much depends on the class.  Every object occupies heap memory.  How much depends on its class.  Many classes and objects also contain references to other objects, and those other objects occupy their own heap memory.  Some objects also have associated native resources, which occupy an idiosyncratic amount of memory.  Local variables occupy stack memory appropriate for their type, though under some circumstances certain local variables may share the same stack memory as others.

In your case (1):

```
String nextPoint=new StringBuilder().append("My").append("next").append("point").toString();

System.out.println(nextPoint);
```

variable `nextPoint` is a local reference variable, consuming stack memory (for a reference, not a whole `String`).  It is initialized by creating a new `StringBuilder` object (on the heap) and appending three Strings to it (each one an object occupying heap memory), and then creating a new `String` object (also occupying heap memory), and storing a reference to it in `nextPoint`.  The `StringBuilder` will have some kind of associated storage for the accumulated character data; this will not overlap that of any of the Strings involved.

Your case (2) differs only in that a reference to the `StringBuilder` is retained instead of a reference to the generated `String`.  That may have implications for code that follows, but it makes no difference to which objects are created and what memory is needed.

> which solution is better when i'm using "nextPoint" varaible or "downPoint" variable?

It depends on what you want to do afterward.  If you're not going to use either of those variables again then the difference is purely stylistic.

> what is result of my code snippet [?]

Put it in a class, run it, and find out for yourself.  Or figure it out from the code.  This one is not something you should need us to answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Both snippets do the same sequence of method calls, being

`new StringBuilder().append("My").append("next").append("point").toString()`,

so their memory usage is (mostly) the same. Only snippet (1) stores a reference to the StringBuilder in a variable, and (2) stores the resulting String reference. But as references are the same size, no matter what the refer to, that results in the same number of bytes occupied.